# Awk gensub transformation

Tags: regex, awk, substitution

```
echo "0.123e2" | gawk '{print gensub(/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)e([0-9]+)/, "\\1 * 10 ^ \\2", "g")}'
```

gives me "0.123 * 10 ^ 2" as a result as expected.
Is there a way to actually tell it to calculate the term to "12.3" ?

In general: Is there a way to modify/transform the matches (\\1,\\2,...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be easier with perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+\.\d+e\d+)/ sprintf("%.1f",$1) /ge' filename
```

With your test data:

```
echo '0.123e2 xyz/$&" 0.3322e12)282 abc' | perl -pe 's/(\d+\.\d+e\d+)/ sprintf("%.1f",$1) /ge'
12.3 xyz/$&" 332200000000.0)282 abc
```

With awk:

```
awk '{ 
      while ( match( $0, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+e[0-9]+/ ) > 0 ) {
       num = sprintf("%.1f", substr( $0, RSTART, RLENGTH ) )
       sub( /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+e[0-9]+/, num )
      }
       print $0
    }' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want to use `printf` to specify the output format:

```
$ echo "0.123e2" | awk '{printf "%.1f\n",$0}' 
12.3
```

Comment: i dont need this gawk script to just use it on this one string.Its for all kinds of numbers in this formart 0.[number]e[number] and replacing it with its calculated value

Comment: I don't care if you want to change the format of one number in scientific notation or 10 million.. the correct way to do this in `awk` is using the `printf` and `sprintf` functions.

Comment: As far as i know does printf have no regex matching function. Please correct me if i'm mistaken, but i think i have to use a regex matching function like gensub for more "random"-input streams like for example: "...0.123e2 xyz/$&" 0.3322e12)282 abc..." which is the case.

Comment: Changing the format from scientific to decimal floating point has absolutely nothing to with regexp! You definitely do **not** want regexp.

Comment: ok so how would you process my proposed "more random" teststring?

Comment: You haven't proposed a "more random" teststring so I could not comment.

Comment: ... and what do you want doing with that string? What is the expected output? Should all the characters be interpreted literal?

Comment: the expected output would be "...12.3 xyz/$&" 332200000000)282 abc..." in words: change the formats from floating point to decimal

Comment: `echo '0.123e2 xyz/$&" 0.3322e12)282 abc' | awk -F'[ )]' '{printf "%.1f %s %.i)%s %s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'`

Comment: oh my god you really seem to love using printf ;-). I see you can do that manually this way. With a more random string i ment really a file with maybe 10 million such strings, where you absolutely can not make any statement about the format. how would you proceed there? Im sorry for my ambigous description.